# How to navigate to another page in react native ignite bowser?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I am new to react native / ignite bowser. I am making a react native / ignite bowser project.

In my app first there is a welcome screen which appears when the app starts. There is a 'continue' button in the welcome screen. When I click the 'continue' button it should go to the login screen. But it shows this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

I am running the app on an actual physical android device.

Can anyone help me? This is my code in github:

```
https://github.com/boidurja/smartcope_new.git
```

This is the part of the code where the error occurs:

```js
    <Button title="Countinue" containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={ ( ) => navigation.navigate('login') }/>
```

in this file:

```
app/screens/auth-screens/welcome-screen.tsx
```

I was told that in this case the issue is that the props property doesn't have the navigation object, coz in new version of the library we have to use react hooks for that check for react-navigation v5 documentation on how to access the navigation prop in react component. I tried it but was not successful.

I see this error
[image]

Comment: Please show the code of the part where the error occurs.

Comment: @hong developer, Hi, I have updated my question to show where the error occurs. Thanks.

Comment: The error is in line no 54 in the file app/screens/auth-screens/welcome-screen.tsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to receive the Navigation object properly. If this is the `component` you use, use the `useNavigation` function.

> `useNavigation` is a hook which gives access to navigation object.
>   It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the
>   component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply
>   nested child.

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const AuthScreensWelcomeScreen: FunctionComponent<AuthScreensWelcomeScreenProps> = observer((props) => {
...
 const navigation = useNavigation();

...
<Button title="Countinue" containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={ ( ) => navigation.navigate('login') }/>
```

OR

> You can get access to the root navigation object through a `ref` and
>   pass it to the `RootNavigation` which we will later use to `navigate`.

**Usage**

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```

```js
// any js module
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';


export const AuthScreensWelcomeScreen: FunctionComponent<AuthScreensWelcomeScreenProps> = observer((props) => {
// ...

<Button title="Countinue" containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={ ( ) => RootNavigation.navigate('login') }/>
```

Comment: sorry it did not work. It showed this error ```Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?```

Comment: First it showed this error: ```Identifier 'navigation' has already been declared```. So I removed this part of the code ```const {
  navigation
 } = props;```. Then it showed the above error.

Comment: I see this error: ```Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?```

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdarv I've shown you a different way to My answer. Would you like to give it a try?

Comment: I had a doubt. What do I write inside ```<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>```

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdarv  Add the Navigator you configured.

Comment: It's working. Thanks. If any error comes I will write later.

Answer (score 0):

In welcomscreen.tsx, try changing this line:

```
const {
        navigation
    } = props;
```

To this:

```
const {
        navigation
    } = this.props;
```

Alternately, you could leave that snippet out and alter the button snippet like this:

```
<Button title="Countinue" containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('login') }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this did not work. It showed this error: ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')```.